# Is there a feature set to make commas prepend, put commas at the beginning of new lines, not at the end?

Tags: prettier

Does prettier have a similar setting in the formatting plugin Beautify?

`"comma_first": true,`

## before formatting

```
// before formatting
const obj = { 
   a : 1, 
   b : 2,
   c : 3 
}
```

## after formatting

```
// after formatting
const obj = { 
   a : 1 
 , b : 2 
 , c : 3 
}
```